# Derby DB adding white-spaces to CHAR values

Tags: database, netbeans, derby

I'm building a desktop application using derby Database... While inserting data into a table which contains several columns having data type "CHAR (10)", the database adds white-spaces to the value. For ex. I'm adding a name "Derby" which is of 5 alphabets, the remaining 5 alphabets are added as white-space. The problem starts when I retrieve these values from DB, those whit-spaces are also retrieved along with the actual value. This doesn't happens with the "VARCHAR" data type. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how the `CHAR` data type is defined in the SQL standard. Derby just follows those rules [as documented in the manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefsqlj13733.html) (and essentially every DBMS complies with these rules, in some you *can* disable this however)

There is nothing you can do to "avoid" this - just use `VARCHAR` if you don't want that padding.

In my personal opinion: the `CHAR` data type is essentially useless nowadays. In almost every DBMS `VARCHAR` is more efficient (as it requires less storage) and does not suffer from this required but annoying padding behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the info... Now i'm using the trim function defined in java while retrieving the values... it helps a bit!

Comment: @Frostem: using `trim()` is an ugly workaround. You should use the proper data type (`varchar`) instead. Just stop using `char` (that is true for any DBMS)

Comment: In my current project, most of the database work is already done. Changing anything now will cause me a lot of work to do again. I'll consider your advice for VARCHAR from the next time!

Comment: It's better to change this now. The work that is needed to fix this will not get less, it will get more over time.